# Is it possible to have gerrit/phabricator(code review) running on one server and git repository on the other? and have them synced?

Tags: git, gerrit, phabricator

Question as in the title. I want to improve our code reviews with tool like gerrit or phabricator. We don't have access to the server hosting our git repository, but we have other server where we can run gerrit or phabricator - depends which one is better/let us do what we want.

First question: is it possible?
Second: how to do it?

Comment: Are you intending on being able to push to both places?  Gerrit and your other hosting provider?  If you limit it to Gerrit, then you can use a post-receive hook to mirror to the other repository.  I do this now with some of my repos.  I host the repos on my own server (for me), but when I push to them, it turns around and pushes them to 1 or 2 more places.  It works very well.  But the technique doesn't support having commits come from both directions.  For that, you'd have to support merging, which also means you need to deal with conflicts.

Comment: I want to have ability to push changes to repository without code review, and I also can't guarantee that my team will be the only people making changes in the repository, so it is possible that we will push changes to both places... What about phabricator? I have used it for about a month, and it is different from gerrit in that sense that you are responsible for pushing changes after code review to repository, where gerrit does it for you.

Comment: I don't much about phabricator, but it appears that it supports remote repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phabricator does not need the master copy of a repository. Many installs (including Phabricator's meta-install) currently use it with GitHub, which does not provide access to the master.

This is the only mode Phabricator operates in right now (it can not currently manage masters) so just follow the normal install instructions for configuration, notably:

http://www.phabricator.com/docs/phabricator/article/Diffusion_User_Guide.html

Comment: I need help on phabricator. I have installed it on ubuntu but I am not able to understand how to install arc and other utilities to use code review. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If developers might push changes to the remote repository, so Gerrit/Phabricator wouldn't know about the changes, there are no good options.  The code review isn't really valid at that point - a developer might push up a change for review which looks perfectly valid, but really those changes are made to a file which was deleted or refactored upstream.

I'm not very familiar with Phabricator, but here are a few options with Gerrit which might work:

1. Can you mount the remote repository locally so that it looks like a local file system to Gerrit?  That would be the ideal solution - Gerrit would push to this repository and catch any merge issues, presenting them to the user.
2. You could use the replication feature of Gerrit to push merged changes to the remote repository.  If there are merge conflicts, I don't know of a good way to handle them.
3. You could write a hook for Gerrit to push merged changes to the remote repository.  This is more flexible than #2 - you could have the hook email you on merge conflicts.
4. With either solution 2 or 3, you need some method of keeping Gerrit's copy of the repositories up-to-date.  A git hook on the remote repository which pushed to Gerrit (bypassing review) is the best option.  Otherwise I think you'd have to have a script which would poll for changes to the remote server and push them to Gerrit.

Comment: That is very helpful answer, thank you! However, looks like I will try to use phabricator.